# sequence of the constructor of two parent classes

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, virtual-inheritance

I have one question on the two version of code.
The only different is to switch the virtual keyword between the parents class.
Is there any reason why this happened?

Version one:

```
#include<iostream> 
using namespace std; 
class Person { 
public: 
    Person(int x) { cout << "Person::Person(int ) called" << endl; } 
    Person()     { cout << "Person::Person() called" << endl; } 
}; 

class Faculty : public Person { 
public: 
    Faculty(int x):Person(x) { 
    cout<<"Faculty::Faculty(int ) called"<< endl; 
    } 
}; 

class Student : virtual public Person { 
public: 
    Student(int x):Person(x) { 
        cout<<"Student::Student(int ) called"<< endl; 
    } 
}; 

class TA : public Faculty, public Student { 
public: 
    TA(int x):Student(x), Faculty(x), Person(x) { 
        cout<<"TA::TA(int ) called"<< endl; 
    } 
}; 

int main() { 
    TA ta1(30); 
}
```

The output of Version:
**Person::Person(int ) called

Person::Person(int ) called

Faculty::Faculty(int ) called

Student::Student(int ) called

TA::TA(int ) called**

Version two:

```
#include<iostream> 
using namespace std; 
class Person { 
public: 
    Person(int x) { cout << "Person::Person(int ) called" << endl; } 
    Person()     { cout << "Person::Person() called" << endl; } 
}; 

class Faculty : virtual public Person { 
public: 
    Faculty(int x):Person(x) { 
    cout<<"Faculty::Faculty(int ) called"<< endl; 
    } 
}; 

class Student :  public Person { 
public: 
    Student(int x):Person(x) { 
        cout<<"Student::Student(int ) called"<< endl; 
    } 
}; 

class TA : public Faculty, public Student { 
public: 
    TA(int x):Student(x), Faculty(x), Person(x) { 
        cout<<"TA::TA(int ) called"<< endl; 
    } 
}; 

int main() { 
    TA ta1(30); 
}
```

The output is:
**Person::Person(int ) called

Faculty::Faculty(int ) called

Person::Person(int ) called

Student::Student(int ) called

TA::TA(int ) called**

Comment: See e.g. [this initialization order reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor#Initialization_order).

Comment: A side question: does `Faculty` entity have a relation "IS A" with the entity `Person`?

Comment: Virtual base classes are initialised first.   So, yes, adding the `virtual` keyword does affect initialisation order.   Inheriting from `Person` once with virtual inheritance and once without still means there are two distinct bases of type `Person`, but the virtual one will be initialised first each time.

Answer (score 3):

The order that classes are initialized is based on the order they're declared in your class's base class specifier list:

1. If this is the most-derived class, virtual base classes are initialized.  Their initialization order is based on a depth-first left-to-right search of this class's base class specifier list.
2. Non-virtual base classes are initialized from left to right
3. This class's members are constructed based on declaration order
4. This class's constructor body runs

This process repeats recursively for each object initialized.

---

For the first example:

1. `TA` is the most-derived class, so its `Person` virtual base object is initialized first.

   - `Person`'s constructor body runs and prints its message.
2. `Faculty` is the first declared base class, so it's initialized next.

   - `Faculty` has a non-virtual base class `Person`, so it initializes its own `Person` sub-object.

     - `Person`'s constructor body runs and prints its message
   - `Faculty`'s constructor body runs and prints its message
3. `Student` is the next base class, so it's initialized next.

   - `Student` is not the most-derived class, so it doesn't get its own `Person` sub-object to initialize.
   - `Student`'s constructor body runs and prints its message
4. `TA`'s constructor body runs and prints its message

The result is that the constructors' bodies are executed in the following order:

1. `Person`
2. `Person`
3. `Faculty`
4. `Student`
5. `TA`

---

For the second example:

1. `TA` is the most-derived class, so its `Person` virtual base object is initialized first.

   - `Person`'s constructor body runs and prints its message.
2. `Faculty` is the first declared base class, so it's initialized next.

   - `Faculty` is not the most-derived class, so it doesn't get its own `Person` sub-object to initialize.
   - `Faculty`'s constructor body runs and prints its message
3. `Student` is the next base class, so it's initialized next.

   - `Student` has a non-virtual base class `Person`, so it initializes its own `Person` sub-object.

     - `Person`'s constructor body runs and prints its message
   - `Student`'s constructor body runs and prints its message
4. `TA`'s constructor body runs and prints its message

The result is that the constructors' bodies are executed in the following order:

1. `Person`
2. `Faculty`
3. `Person`
4. `Student`
5. `TA`

---

Note that in both cases, there are *two* `Person` subobjects.  For `Faculty` and `Student` to share a single `Person` subobject, both would have to inherit virutally from `Person`  i.e.:

```
class Person {
public:
    Person(int x) { cout << "Person::Person(int) called" << endl; }
    Person()      { cout << "Person::Person() called" << endl; }
};

class Faculty : virtual public Person {
public:
    Faculty(int x) : Person(x) {
        cout<<"Faculty::Faculty(int) called"<< endl;
    }
};

class Student : virtual public Person {
public:
    Student(int x) : Person(x) {
        cout<<"Student::Student(int) called"<< endl;
    }
};

class TA : public Faculty, public Student {
public:
    TA(int x) : Student(x), Faculty(x), Person(x) {
        cout<<"TA::TA(int) called"<< endl;
    }
};
```

In this case the logic would be:

1. `TA` is the most-derived class, so its `Person` virtual base object is initialized first.

   - `Person`'s constructor body runs and prints its message.
2. `Faculty` is the first declared base class, so it's initialized next.

   - `Faculty` is not the most-derived class, so it doesn't get its own `Person` sub-object to initialize.
   - `Faculty`'s constructor body runs and prints its message
3. `Student` is the next base class, so it's initialized next.

   - `Student` is not the most-derived class, so it doesn't get its own `Person` sub-object to initialize.
   - `Student`'s constructor body runs and prints its message
4. `TA`'s constructor body runs and prints its message

Resulting in the class' constructor bodies executing in the following order:

1. `Person`
2. `Faculty`
3. `Student`
4. `TA`

Answer (score 2):

The order of the initialization is set according to left to right for the inherited base classes. It basically ignores the order you have set in the constructor list.

```
class TA : public Faculty, public Student { 
public: 
    TA(int x):Student(x), Faculty(x) { 
        cout<<"TA::TA(int ) called"<< endl; 
    } 
};
```

Will initialize for the first case as:

```
class TA : public Faculty, public Student { 
public: 
    TA(int x):Faculty(x), Student(x) { 
        cout<<"TA::TA(int ) called"<< endl; 
    } 
};
```

*But* virtual base classes are initialized firstly, so we have:

```
class TA : public Faculty, public Student { 
public: 
    TA(int x):Person(x), Faculty(x), Student(x) { 
        cout<<"TA::TA(int ) called"<< endl; 
    } 
};
```

Now, when `Faculty(x)` is initialized, `Person(x)` is initialized (since it derives from it). Then `Student` it initialized, and lastly, the `TA`-object itself.

You can see the incorrectness in the initializer list by compiling with `-Wall`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, to implement **"diamond" multiple inheritance** in correct way, **both your classes Faculty and Student must be virtually inherited from Person.**
In this case you'll see only one call to Person's constructor in your output. And this is the purpose: to call grandparent's constructor only once.

You probably use very non-restrictive compiler, because restrictive compilation of your code (using VS2017, for example) immediately reports an error: `error C2385: ambiguous access of 'Person'` . And this is the expected behavior.

Additional Explanation: using **virtual** inheritance postpones call to inheriting class constructor to be performed by it's "grandchild". In your case, class TA is grandchild of Person and only it calls Person's constructor, while Faculty and Student don't.